# How to Inject only one variable using guice?

Tags: java, dependency-injection, guice, inject

I have a class something like this:

```
public class Person {
    private final Object1 object1;  //taking this as constructor parameter
    private final Object2 object2;  //want to inject only this?

    @Inject
    public Person(final Object1 object1) {
        this.object1 = object1;
    }
}
```

Lets say I want a constructor which only takes object1 in parameters and I want to inject object2?
How can I achieve that?

Comment: Why do you need to inject dependencies manually?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: Maybe I didn't understood. You want to inject obj1 via constructor injection and object2 via field injection?

Comment: yeah right ! Is there any way I could do that??

Comment: Did you try to @inject on the field? But you should prefer make a choice...constructor or field injection...both is very strange

Comment: I already have a constructor that inject both variables but my question is can I have 2 constructor one which injects both and one that injects only object2?

Answer (score 0):

You can only inject into the one ctor.

But you could use a factory. Look at this

https://google.github.io/guice/api-docs/3.0/javadoc/com/google/inject/assistedinject/FactoryModuleBuilder.html

Depending on the argument (`@Assisted` Object1/Object2) you choose to pass through the factory it will delegate to the adequate constructor.